# buddypress API whith GET/POST messages for an android app

Tags: android, wordpress, buddypress

I have a WordPress site that uses the BuddyPress plugin. I want to build an Android app that allows the user to get messages and set messages and other options . Is there a REST API for Buddypress that I can use?
I found [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-json-api/faq/) but I only see get methods !

if there is no existing API for what I’m asking, what can I do to consume buddypress services from my android app?